# How can I update a WASM ISC contracts?

Tags: smart-contract

I'm looking for a way to modify/upgrade my deployed contract functions while keeping the state untouched. is there an example somewhere on doing this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about EVM contracts, then there are several examples on how to write an upgradable smart contract. [From OpenZepplin](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/learn/upgrading-smart-contracts).

If you're talking about WASM contracts, then I don't believe there's any example as such yet.

Comment: more importantly, in WASM based SC, is there a way to modify the underlying ISC state storage described in the ```schema.yaml``` after being deployed?

Comment: You'll need to deploy a new contact. Or if you have constructed the contact in a way that the state storage is variable, perhaps it's possible. But updating `schema.yml` will not be possible past deploying.